# Replace string in a file using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use the sed functionality of bash scripting to find and replce the content in  a file. Not sure if my approach is correct or not but I dont want to go with regex.

**Input:**

```
 <if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>

    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
    <VMArg name="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$VDISTDIR/system/conf/logging.properties"/>
    <VMArg name="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///$VDISTDIR/system/conf/log4j2.yaml"/>
```

**Expected:**

```
 <if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>
This is the replaced text
    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
    <VMArg name="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$VDISTDIR/system/conf/logging.properties"/>
    <VMArg name="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///$VDISTDIR/system/conf/log4j2.yaml"/>
```

Trying to develop something like below but unfortunately its not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
find='<if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>

    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>'

replace='<if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>

    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>'

sed "s/$find/$replace/g" filename.input
```

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "unfortunately its not working". Why is there a ```\``` before `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: If the question is "replace empty row with text" this might work `awk 'NF==0{$0 = "This is the replaced text"}1' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:
`sed -i -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -Ee 's/(<VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"\/>\n\s+<\/if>)/\1\nThis Is replaced text/' file`

Working solution:

````
$ cat file
<if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>

    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
    <VMArg name="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$VDISTDIR/system/conf/logging.properties"/>
    <VMArg name="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///$VDISTDIR/system/conf/log4j2.yaml"/>

$ cat file  | sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -Ee 's/(<VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"\/>\n\s+<\/if>)/\1\nThis Is replaced text/'
<if property="headless">
        <VMArg name="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
    </if>
This Is replaced text

    <VMArg name="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
    <VMArg name="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$VDISTDIR/system/conf/logging.properties"/>
    <VMArg name="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///$VDISTDIR/system/conf/log4j2.yaml"/>```
````

Comment: No need for the `cat` though, just `sed -e ... file`

Comment: @Jetchisel In solution, there is sed without cat, you need `-i` to do in place change thought. The cat is only to show solution working :)

Comment: Oh, right, I did not see that :-)